# Apart expression returns unevaluated

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I want to perform a partial fraction expansion in the variable `qp` by 
treating all other variables as constants (some real, others complex). My code, shown below, does not seem to give me anything.

```
Apart[
  -((q qp^3 vq (I Abs[wn] + qp v[-1]) (v[-1] - v[1])^2 (-I Abs[wn] + qp v[1]) 
      (wn^2 + q qp v[-1] v[1]) (-wn^2 + qp^2 v[-1] v[1])) / 
    (2 π^2 (q + qp) (-q1 + qp) β (qp - (I wn)/v[-1]) (qp + (I wn)/v[-1]) 
      v[-1]^2 (-I Abs[wn] + q v[-1]) (2 vq v[-1] + π v[-1]^2) 
      (qp - (Sqrt[π] wn)/Sqrt[-v[-1] (2 vq + π v[-1])]) 
      (qp + (Sqrt[π] wn)/Sqrt[-v[-1] (2 vq + π v[-1])]) 
      (qp - (I wn)/v[1])^2 (qp + (I wn)/v[1])^2 v[1]^4 (I Abs[wn] + q v[1]))), 
  qp]
```

Comment: I'll look into it next week. I agree this behavior seems weird, not yet sure if it is a bug though. My guess is `Apart` is thrown off by having algebraics (radicals) present in the input, even though they do not involve the variable of interest.

Comment: I think it now works to specifications. Gives a fairly large result though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `APart` package by Feng Feng (https://github.com/F-Feng/APart)

```
<< Apart`

InnerCollectFunction = Identity;


exp = -((q qp^3 vq (I Abs[wn] + 
        qp v[-1]) (v[-1] - v[1])^2 (-I Abs[wn] + qp v[1]) (wn^2 + 
        q qp v[-1] v[1]) (-wn^2 + qp^2 v[-1] v[1]))/(2 \[Pi]^2 (q + 
        qp) (-q1 + 
        qp) \[Beta] (qp - (I wn)/v[-1]) (qp + (I wn)/
         v[-1]) v[-1]^2 (-I Abs[wn] + 
        q v[-1]) (2 vq v[-1] + \[Pi] v[-1]^2) (qp - (Sqrt[\[Pi]] wn)/
         Sqrt[-v[-1] (2 vq + \[Pi] v[-1])]) (qp + (Sqrt[\[Pi]] wn)/
         Sqrt[-v[-1] (2 vq + \[Pi] v[-1])]) (qp - (I wn)/
          v[1])^2 (qp + (I wn)/v[1])^2 v[1]^4 (I Abs[wn] + q v[1])))

ApartAll2[exp_, vars_] := 
 Module[{tmp, VF}, 
  tmp = Distribute[VF[Expand[exp, Alternatives @@ vars]]];
  tmp = tmp /. VF[ex_] :> ApartAll[ex, vars];
  Return[tmp];]

AbsoluteTiming[res = ApartAll2[exp, {qp}];]

res // RemoveApart
```

The evaluation requires less than one 30 seconds. However, one should say that by
default `APart` would also have [troubles](https://github.com/F-Feng/APart/issues/2) with this expression. By setting 
`InnerCollectFunction = Identity;` we skip the simplification of fairly complicated prefactors and hence can obtain the final result faster.